# how to focus contentEditable div focus manually React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contenteditable

I am new to react,I am just getting content from contentieditable when user click on a button and contentEditable should appear with focus.But I could focus contenteditable this.refs returns an empty object and there are similar question on stackoverflow but nothing helped me.I have no idea why this.refs returns an empty object.Thanks in advance

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import trimHtml from 'trim-html'
import * as privateTodoActions from '../../../actions/todoActions'


class PersonelTodo extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            newTodo:false,
            currentTodo:""
        };


    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.fetchPrivateTodos();
    }
    newTodo = () => {
        if(this.state.newTodo){
            this.setState({
                newTodo:false
            })

        }else{
            this.setState({
                newTodo:true
            });

            console.log(this.refs) // empty Object {}


        }


    };
    handleTodoInput = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            currentTodo:e.target.innerHTML
        })
    };
    postTodo = () => {
        if(this.state.currentTodo !== ""){
            let payload = {
                todoCon:this.state.currentTodo.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, ""),
                isPrivate:true
            };
            this.props.postPrivateTodo(payload);
            this.refs.todoInput.innerHTML = "";

            this.setState({
                currentTodo:""
            })
        }

    };
    handleShorcut = (e) => {

        if(e.keyCode === 13 && e.ctrlKey){
            e.preventDefault();

            this.refs.todoInput.innerHTML = "";
            this.postTodo()
        }
    };
    renderAllTodos(){

        return this.props.privateTodo.get('todoList').map(data => {
            let {html} =  trimHtml( data.todoCon, { limit: 180 })
            return(
                <div key={data._id} className="UniquesingleTodo singleTodo">
                    {/*<div className="labels">*/}
                        {/*<div className="redLabel ColorLabel">*/}
                        {/*</div>*/}
                        {/*<div className="GreenLabel ColorLabel">*/}
                        {/*</div>*/}
                    {/*</div>*/}
                    <div className="todoContentEdit" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: html}} />
                </div>
            )
        })


    }
    render(){

        return(
            <div className="todoContainer">
                <div className="PersonelTodoSection">
                    <div className="PersonelSectionTitle">
                        <div className="IconSingleTodoCat">
                            <svg className="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path d="M17.638,6.181h-3.844C13.581,4.273,11.963,2.786,10,2.786c-1.962,0-3.581,1.487-3.793,3.395H2.362c-0.233,0-0.424,0.191-0.424,0.424v10.184c0,0.232,0.191,0.424,0.424,0.424h15.276c0.234,0,0.425-0.191,0.425-0.424V6.605C18.062,6.372,17.872,6.181,17.638,6.181 M13.395,9.151c0.234,0,0.425,0.191,0.425,0.424S13.629,10,13.395,10c-0.232,0-0.424-0.191-0.424-0.424S13.162,9.151,13.395,9.151 M10,3.635c1.493,0,2.729,1.109,2.936,2.546H7.064C7.271,4.744,8.506,3.635,10,3.635 M6.605,9.151c0.233,0,0.424,0.191,0.424,0.424S6.838,10,6.605,10c-0.233,0-0.424-0.191-0.424-0.424S6.372,9.151,6.605,9.151 M17.214,16.365H2.786V7.029h3.395v1.347C5.687,8.552,5.332,9.021,5.332,9.575c0,0.703,0.571,1.273,1.273,1.273c0.702,0,1.273-0.57,1.273-1.273c0-0.554-0.354-1.023-0.849-1.199V7.029h5.941v1.347c-0.495,0.176-0.849,0.645-0.849,1.199c0,0.703,0.57,1.273,1.272,1.273s1.273-0.57,1.273-1.273c0-0.554-0.354-1.023-0.849-1.199V7.029h3.395V16.365z" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <p>Personel</p>

                        <button onClick={this.newTodo}>Add</button>

                    </div>
                    <div className="PersonalTodoContainer">



                        {this.renderAllTodos()}



                        {this.state.newTodo ? <div className="todoInput--unique">
                            <div onKeyDown={this.handleShorcut} onInput={this.handleTodoInput} spellCheck="false" ref={(input) => {this.todoInput = input}}  contentEditable="true" className="inputCon"/>

                            <div className="newTodoBut">
                                <button onClick={this.postTodo} className="addtodobtn">Add</button>
                                <button onClick={this.postTodo} className="closeAddtodo">
                                    <svg fill="#fff" className="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                        <path d="M10.185,1.417c-4.741,0-8.583,3.842-8.583,8.583c0,4.74,3.842,8.582,8.583,8.582S18.768,14.74,18.768,10C18.768,5.259,14.926,1.417,10.185,1.417 M10.185,17.68c-4.235,0-7.679-3.445-7.679-7.68c0-4.235,3.444-7.679,7.679-7.679S17.864,5.765,17.864,10C17.864,14.234,14.42,17.68,10.185,17.68 M10.824,10l2.842-2.844c0.178-0.176,0.178-0.46,0-0.637c-0.177-0.178-0.461-0.178-0.637,0l-2.844,2.841L7.341,6.52c-0.176-0.178-0.46-0.178-0.637,0c-0.178,0.176-0.178,0.461,0,0.637L9.546,10l-2.841,2.844c-0.178,0.176-0.178,0.461,0,0.637c0.178,0.178,0.459,0.178,0.637,0l2.844-2.841l2.844,2.841c0.178,0.178,0.459,0.178,0.637,0c0.178-0.176,0.178-0.461,0-0.637L10.824,10z" />
                                    </svg>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div> : ""}


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return{
        privateTodo:state.privateTodo
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,privateTodoActions)(PersonelTodo)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you get the ref in your ref callback, you have to access it with **this.todoInput** instead of this.refs.todoInput. As far as I am aware, it would only hold the ref in the refs object if you do something like: ref="todoInput" on your component.